# Boost "CreateProcess failed"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

This is a "Hello World" test built in Visual Studio 2017 (v141).  I suspect the problem is some 32-bit/64-bit mismatch, but I'm not sure how to check that.

I'm compiling the following as Debug x86 (it gives some warnings that I turn off with _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS but I think they aren't relevant and I also do a #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501).  Attempting to compile as x64 throws TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm linking to libboost_XXX-vc141-mt-1_64.lib libraries.

The actual code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/windows.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::process;
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int result = bp::system("echo Hello");
}
```

which throws "Microsoft C++ exception: boost::process::process_error at memory location 0x0137EE34."

Comment: There is no executable file named "echo.exe".  It is a command for the command processor.  Like dir, copy, if, etc.  You could execute it with "cmd.exe /c echo Hello".

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that as soon as the current install finishes. My code line does work if I used std::system rather than bp::system though.

Comment: Sure, the system() function does not use CreateProcess(), it asks Cmd.exe to do the job.  The Unix way.  It is not clear to me why Boost doesn't use ShellExecuteEx(), the windows-centric way to ask the shell to execute a command.  Oh well.

Comment: Pinging @KlemensMorgenstern for the question by Hans Passant

Comment: Have you tried handling the exception to see what it says? (/cc @HansPassant for previous message)

Comment: That worked - please post it as an answer.  Very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently on windows, there's no concept of a default shell. You can explicitly invoke one:

```
int result = bp::system(bp::search_path("cmd.exe"), "/c", "echo Hello");
```

> **NOTE** Optionally use [`%COMSPEC%`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMSPEC) to locate command shell

```
int result = bp::system(bp::search_path("cmd.exe"), "/c", "echo %COMSPEC%");
```